# error removing child node from parent node in spriteKit Swift4

Tags: xcode, swift3, sprite-kit

I made a parallax background, in GameScene.sks I added an empty node, added two sprites to an empty node. I have a reset button, when I click on it I need the background to be removed and added to its position (restarted), but when I add in scrollBg.removeAllChildren restart function I error occurs, how do I properly add and remove children from the scene ?

```
  import SpriteKit
  import GameplayKit



class GameScene: SKScene {

     var player: SKSpriteNode!
     var scrollBg: SKNode!
     var spawnTimer: CFTimeInterval = 0
     let fixedDelta: CFTimeInterval = 1.0/60.0 /* 60 FPS */
     let scrollSpeed: CGFloat = 700
     var sinceTouch: CFTimeInterval = 0


       func resetGameScene() {

        scrollBG.removeAllChildren()
        player.removeAllChildren()
        player.position = CGPoint(x: 590 , y: 690)

        pauseButton()

      }

      override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        player = childNode(withName: "player") as? SKSpriteNode
        scrollBg = childNode(withName: "scrollBG")!

        resetGameScene()
      }


       func scrollWorld() {

         scrollBg.position.y -= scrollSpeed * CGFloat(fixedDelta)

           for ground in scrollBg.children as! [SKSpriteNode] {

         let groundPosition = scrollBg.convert(ground.position, to: 
                                                             self)

            if groundPosition.y <= -ground.size.width  {
               let newPosition = CGPoint(x: groundPosition.x, y: 
                   (self.size.width ) + ground.size.width * 2)

              ground.position = self.convert(newPosition, to: 
                                                          scrollBg)
               }
            }
         }



       override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

           sinceTouch+=fixedDelta
           spawnTimer+=fixedDelta
           scrollWorld()
           }







       }
```

Comment: You keep pointing to scrollBG through `scrollWorld()` with the `update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval)` method.

Comment: What should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: when the restart method works, all the child nodes are deleted, how to add them back?

Comment: Put a guard statement down in the update method that checks if scrollBG is nil. If not then execute the code you currently have in the update method

Comment: I did not understand how to do